# How do I loop through html objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop through several objects within the same `id`, instead of generating a new `id` for each object and writing out the script, as it is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_object(id) {
   var object = null;
   if (document.layers) {
    object = document.layers[id];
   } else if (document.all) {
    object = document.all[id];
   } else if (document.getElementById) {
    object = document.getElementById(id);
   }
   return object;
  }
get_object("inputdata").innerHTML=DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("inputdata").innerHTML,1);
get_object("inputdata2").innerHTML=DrawCode39Barcode(get_object("inputdata2").innerHTML,1);
</script>
```

Comment: `document.layers`? `document.all`? Why are you writing code for Netscape 4 and Internet Explorer 5.0?

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: Could you try to be a little more descriptive? Like what is your requirement? Do you have several HTML elements under one element and you want to iterate over all those inner elements?

Answer (score 1):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (with a CSS class selector as its argument) and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will both return an array-like [HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements that are a member of a given class. You can use it with a simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Im not sure how to implement this? I accidentally said class when intending id.

Comment: @user241619 — You **cannot** have multiple elements with the same id. The HTML specification forbids it and it defeats the whole purpose of using an id. If you want multiple elements with a shared identifying feature, use a class, that is what class is designed for.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What does this look like in terms of the above code. Im not entirely familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For example looping all **Input**  I use this code

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('Some fields are empty');
       return false;
    }
});
```